# Menu layout breaks if you zoom out in chrome

Tags: css

Please visit [site](http://www.iamvishal.com/pureecn/)

In chrome if you zoom to `75%` the secondary menu breaks as per below
picture.

[image]

There are many related topics on stackoverflow. I tried them
but it did not work for me. Some of the things I tried:

1. `position: absolute`;
2. Change my container from `div` to `span`;
3. Change font from `px` to `em`;

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the problem is relative to the property `width`. If you remove or modify like this the `#secondary_links` with a width to `100%`:

```
#secondary_links {
    color: #0076AB;
    font-family: Times New Roman,Times,serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 228px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 764px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
}
```